# NBitcoin and generating addresses from xpub key

Tags: c#, bitcoin

I'm attempting to write an algorithm that generates public bitcoin addresses from a known xpubkey.  The key I'm using for testing can be found at blockchain.info at

https://blockchain.info/xpub/xpub6CUGRUonZSQ4TWtTMmzXdrXDtypWKiKrhko4egpiMZbpiaQL2jkwSB1icqYh2cfDfVxdx4df189oLKnC5fSwqPfgyP3hooxujYzAu3fDVmz

I'm trying something like this to generate the address on the path 0,0,0, as below:

```
        var pubkey = new ExtPubKey(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("6CUGRUonZSQ4TWtTMmzXdrXDtypWKiKrhko4egpiMZbpiaQL2jkwSB1icqYh2cfDfVxdx4df189oLKnC5fSwqPfgyP3hooxujYzAu3fDVmz"));
        Console.Writeline(pubkey.Derive(0).Derive(0).Derive(0).PubKey.GetAddress(Network.Main));
```

but I'm not fully understanding something because I get a 'Invalid point encoding 103' when trying to instantiate the ExtPubKey.

Answer (score 3):

Via https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=1242247.0

```
var pubkey = ExtPubKey.Parse("xpub6CUGRUonZSQ4TWtTMmzXdrXDtypWKiKrhko4egpiMZbpiaQL2jkwSB1icqYh2cfDfVxdx4df189oLKnC5fSwqPfgyP3hooxujYzAu3fDVmz");
var newAddress = pubkey.Derive(0).Derive(0).PubKey.GetAddress(Network.Main);
Console.WriteLine(newAddress);
```

Tested, generates expected first address.

Answer (score 0):

You get invalid encoding, because you are trying to encode

"6CUGRUonZSQ4TWtTMmzXdrXDtypWKiKrhko4egpiMZbpiaQL2jkwSB1icqYh2cfDfVxdx4df189oLKnC5fSwqPfgyP3hooxujYzAu3fDVmz"

instead of

"**xpub**6CUGRUonZSQ4TWtTMmzXdrXDtypWKiKrhko4egpiMZbpiaQL2jkwSB1icqYh2cfDfVxdx4df189oLKnC5fSwqPfgyP3hooxujYzAu3fDVmz"

You are missing **xpub** from the beginning.